# Nativescript error on build on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nativescript

I'm trying to build an app using nativescript on android platform. when I run `tns prepare android` all goes well but when I run `tns build android` I keep getting this error:

```
AILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForF0Debug'.
        com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
        java.lang.RuntimeException: 
        com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:   
        java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
        com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
        org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException:
    Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
* Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

2: Task failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':buildMetadata'.
    Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 137
```

The os I'm running is ubuntu 14

Comment: can you please post tns doctor output?

Comment: I fix the problem by adding more RAM memory

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem by adding more RAM memory